# Automatic conversion of intrinsic types to enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums, intrinsics

Problem sounds painfully familiar.
Assume you have enum:

```
enum MyEnum {first, second, third};
```

Now I want convert some int to MyEnum. Naive approach

```
int i = 2;
MyEnum e = (MyEnum)i;
```

Seems OK, but it is not. First, 2 will be converted to 'third' and not to 'second' as one would expect. Second, this conversion is dumb and I would like a smart one. 
Motivation is as follows:

```
void foo(MyEnum e) { ... }
...
foo(2);
```

And that foo() should always receive 'second' for 2 no matter what is actual value of this enum. 
There are 2 obvious solutions:

1. Write conversion function and always invoke it
2. Overload casting operator

1st solution is obviously terrible. Don't want write `foo(convetIntToMyEnum(2));`

I want write foo(2) and compiler will automatically invoke my conversion function. So 2nd solution is what I need. If 'int' was my own class, then overloading of cast operator is trivial. But 'int' is intrinsic type.

I vaguely remember there is possibility for that, but can't find it. Appreciate cure for my blond moment.

Comment: Just do `enum MyEnum {first = 1, second, third};`. Problem solved.

Comment: No, I don't want that. In particular enum can be {first=0x1000, second=0x2000 ... }. Hint: enum represents some configuration for HW, so I am not really free to choose values for enum items

Comment: So why the heck would 1 map to 0x1000? That's a bit absurd. If you really want to pursue this strange desire to obfuscate your own code, consider using a class instead of an enum. Or a lookup table. Or *literally anything* besides an implicit conversion that turns numbers into other numbers.

Comment: As I explained above, it is hardware configuration where arbitrary number 0x1000 has very specific meaning of "first". Absurd it or not - that's not was my question. My question is "how?" and not "why?". Thank you.

Comment: And one more clarification. How to implement conversion I know myself. My question is how to overload cast operator for 'int' (or any other intrinsic type  of C++)

Comment: The only place you are permitted to overload conversion operators is as nonstatic class member functions, so you can't because `MyEnum` is not a class.

Comment: @Noname: given `void foo(MyEnum e)`, why wouldn't you just call `foo(second)` instead of `foo(2)`? What is the motivation for calling `foo()` with an arbitrary number instead of an enum element's assigned name? Are you getting the number from a source that is only known at runtime?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Reason is that I need convert user input to enum. And I don't really want convert from 'int' and not really to MyEnum. I want convert some intrinsic type to some enumerated type **automatically** by invoking my converter implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot overload the "casting operator" (normally this is either a "converting constructor" or a "user defined conversion operator") for an enum, since it's not a class and thus cannot have member functions or constructors.

You'd likely want something like this:

```
class my_enum
{
public:
    enum MyEnum {first=0x1000, second=0x2000, third=...};

private:
    MyEnum m_value;

public:
    my_enum(int _value) {
        switch (_value) {
            case 1: m_value = first;  break;
            case 2: m_value = second; break;
            case 3: m_value = third;  break;
            default: throw std::invalid_argument("invalid value");
        }
    }

    operator int() const {
        switch (m_value) {
            case first:  return 1;
            case second: return 2;
            case third:  return 3;
            default:     return 0;
        }
    }
};

void foo(my_enum e)
{
    ...
}
```

You can define whatever mapping from `int` to `enum value` that you want, as long as it's invertible. Because the constructor and cast operator are not explicit, this will allow the implicit conversions you want.

Comment: Apparently you are right. I looked through my old code library and found out that 'operator <<' was overloaded (and it works for native types as well), but cast operator seems indeed very special.
Yet looks quite stupid, as in C++ introduced function references just to be able write foo(myObj) instead of foo(&myObj). But no user-defined conversion from native types to enums.

Answer (score 0):

There is the third and obvious solution: don't use an integer as argument to your function, and instead directly use your enum. Just make it an enum class while you're at it! Added bonus: increased code clarity. This is really no reason to start writing all kinds of unexpected conversions for a bad function prototype.

If these functions are given to you from an external API, well then wrap them in a properly typed way. If you need the raw integral value of the enum members, just call an explicit conversion function then and there. But by the sound of it that should be when accessing the hardware itself, so these call sites can then also be wrapped and you'd be free to the right thing in all the layers above.

Comment: I know I can call converter explicitly. If you read carefully my post, you would notice that I mentioned it as option 1.
But I don't want call converter explicitly, I want compiler call converter implicitly.

Comment: If you read my answer carefully, you'll notice I'm also telling you to not call foo(2), but instead foo(MyEnum::second). Which is not an option you consider.

Comment: Well can't argue, the answer "don't do what you need" is an ultimate answer to practically any question :) yet I have reasons to convert native type to enum.